# Failing to show $\xi$-gauge-independence in an abelian Spontaneously Broken Gauge Theories (SBGT)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, gauge

I am studying the following paper:

> Appelquist, Carazzone, Goldman & Quinn, *Renormalization and Gauge Independence in Spontaneously Broken Gauge Theories,* https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.1747

I am having trouble following its appendix calculations. More specifically following the feynman rules given below, I cannot include the external momenta factors that are presented in the paper's results. As a consequence I cannot show the $\xi$ gauge independence of the process.

The rules are:

[image]

The process is:

[image]

The appendix calculation:

[image]

My questions are the following:

1. How are the external momenta included (especially in A7 or A5), e.g $q^2_1 + q^2_2 + q^2_3 - 6 h \lambda^2$?
2. What is the general approach to this problem independent of the methodology used in the paper, should I just use brute force calculation and hope for the best, or is there any other way?

P.S The pencile drawed circles is what I am able to calculate using those rules.
Be careful with the notation, the paper origins back to 1973.